# CustomCell Dealloc in iPhone

Tags: iphone

When we create Custom Cell and use it to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method, Whether we can dealloc its objects? Will it make any issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you mean -release rather than -dealloc -- you should never send -dealloc to any object yourself, of course.

If you've got a custom UITableViewCell subclass, the right thing to do is to let the cell manage it's own instance variables or properties. So your cell class might look like:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
}

@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *cellData;

@end
```

Then, in your table delegate's -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, when you get one of your cells back from -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, you can just say:

```
cell.cellData = nil;
```

to prepare your cell for its next use. Setting the cellData property to nil will cause the property's setter to release its old string. This isn't strictly necessary if you're just going to set the cellData property to some other string anyway, but I think it's good practice to set a cell back to a known, empty state before you set it up for its new row. Another way to do that is to implement -prepareForReuse in the cell subclass.

Comment: - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
 }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [lblTitle release];
 [lblDetailText release];
 [DetailDisclosureButton release];
 [frontImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
In Custom cell class, I have dealloc objects. Whether it is right way?

Comment: Hard to say definitively without seeing code, but generally no, you wouldn't want to do that.